# ASCII art exercise, but I don't understand this solution

Tags: kotlin, fold, ascii-art

I'm doing the codingame exercises and I managed to finish the ASCII Art problem, it was long and difficult but I did it.
Now I read one of the solutions and it was done in 5 lines of code!
I'm trying to understand it but I'm failing to do so, can someone help me with a step by step explanation?

The test gives you an input of:

Line 1: the width L of a letter represented in ASCII art. All letters are the same width.

Line 2: the height H of a letter represented in ASCII art. All letters are the same height.

Line 3: The line of text T, composed of N ASCII characters.

Following lines: the string of characters ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ? Represented in ASCII art.

This is one of the solutions:

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val L = readLine()!!.toInt()
    val H = readLine()!!.toInt()
    val T = readLine()!!.toUpperCase().replace("[^A-Z]".toRegex(), "[")

    val rows = (0 until H).map{readLine()!!}

    (0 until H).map{h -> T.fold(""){ a, c -> a + rows[h].substring((c-'A')*L, (c-'A')*L+L) }}.forEach{println(it)}
}
```

I'll be very grateful for your help :)

PS. I'm not sure what does *.fold* and *.map*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze line by line.

```
val L = readLine()!!.toInt()
```

Reads an `Int` and puts into variable `L`.

```
val H = readLine()!!.toInt()
```

Reads another `Int` and puts into variable `H`.

```
val T = readLine()!!
    .toUpperCase()
    .replace("[^A-Z]".toRegex(), "[")
```

Reads a `String`, converts all its letters to uppercase characters (so `a` becomes `A`), replace anything that is not a letter with the `[` character (the `[^A-Z]` syntax is from RegEx, not Kotlin) and puts into variable `T`.

```
val rows = (0 until H).map{ readLine()!! }
```

Creates a list with numbers from 0 to H - 1 and, for each number, transforms it into a `String` provided by the user (the `map` function transforms a list of type `T1` to a list of type `T2`; in this case, it transforms a list of `Int`, created by `0 until H`, into a list of `String`, which is the result of `readLine()!!`). Puts the list into the variable `rows`.

```
(0 until H).map{ h ->
    T.fold(""){ a, c ->
        a + rows[h].substring((c-'A')*L, (c-'A')*L+L)
    }
}
.forEach{ println(it) }
```

Creates a list with numbers from 0 to H - 1 and, for each number `h`, transforms it into a `String`.

Before explaining how this `String` is created, let's first analyze what's happening inside `fold`.

- The `fold` receiver (i.e. the variable that is before the `.` when calling `fold`) is a `String`, since the variable `T` is a `String`.
- There are two arguments, `a` and `c`, where `a` is a `String` (same type of the receiver) and `c` is a `Char` (because `String` is a collection of `Char`s). We can only use `fold` in collections, and when doing so, the first argument will be same type of its receiver and the second argument will be the same type of its receiver elements.
- There is an implicit return, which is the argument `a` concatenated with a substring of the `h`-th element of the variable `rows` (since `rows` is a `List<String>`, as we seen above, any element of this list will be a `String`; also consider that a) the first element of this list is in the 0th position of this list and so on, and b) the notation `x[i]` being the `i`-th element of list `x`; that's how Kotlin manages list access).
- This substring starts at position `(c - 'A') * L` and ends at position `(c - 'A') * L + L`. To understand it, think of `Char` as a number. So, when you write 'A', actually you're writing 65. That's a convention named ASCII. So when you do `'A' - 'A'`, you're doing 65 - 65, that's 0. Same goes for `'B' - 'A'`, that means 66 - 65 (since `'B'` is one position ahead of `A` in ASCII), that's 1. Since `L` is also a `Int`, just replace it into the expression and you'll end up with a `Int`.

But what are these two arguments, `a` and `c`? `fold` is nothing but a loop. In the first iteration, `a == ""` (the value between parenthesis after calling `fold`) and `c == T[0]` (i.e. the first `Char` of the variable `T`, which is the receiver). Some value is returned (in this case, the value of `a` concatenated with the substring of `rows[h]`) and, in the next iteration, `a == <returned value by a and T[0]>` and `c == T[1]`. In the next iteration, `a == <returned value by a and T[1]>` and `c == T[2]`. The loop is repeated until all the elements of `T` are processed.

Finally, in the `forEach`, each `String` created by `fold` is printed. If still in doubt, just print each variable in the screen and try to understand:

```
(0 until H).map{ h ->
    println("h=$h")
    T.fold(""){ a, c ->
        println("a=$a, c=$c")
        println("c - 'A' = ${c - 'A'}")
        a + rows[h].substring((c-'A')*L, (c-'A')*L+L)
    }
}
```

Hope you get the idea.

---

**EDIT**: I tried to put the response in a comment but I think it was too long, so I've made an edit.

For better understanding, let's define a function `printAscii`, which is your original function, but with arguments being the inputs. Don't worry if you don't know what a function is.

```kotlin
fun printAscii(L: Int, H: Int, T: String, rows: List<String>) {
    (0 until H).map{ h ->
        T.fold(""){ a, c ->
            a + rows[h].substring((c-'A')*L, (c-'A')*L+L)
        }
    }.forEach{ println(it) }
}
```

You can call a function like this:

```kotlin
printAscii(L = 1, H = 2, T = "some string", rows = listOf("string1", "string2"))
```

In this case, `L` will be equal to `1`, `H` will be equal to `2`, `T` will be equal to `"some string"` and `rows` will be equal to `listOf("string1", "string2")`. Now, let's play with it:

```kotlin
printAscii(L = 1, H = 1, T = "ABCDE", rows = listOf("12345")) // the output is 12345
printAscii(L = 1, H = 1, T = "AACDE", rows = listOf("12345")) // the output is 11345
printAscii(L = 1, H = 1, T = "ABCBA", rows = listOf("12345")) // the output is 12321
printAscii(L = 1, H = 1, T = "EDCBA", rows = listOf("12345")) // the output is 54321
printAscii(L = 1, H = 1, T = "AAAAA", rows = listOf("12345")) // the output is 11111
```

You can see that `T` variable defines how `rows` will be printed.

Now, let's change the `L` variable to `2`.

```
printAscii(L = 2, H = 1, T = "ABCDE", rows = listOf("1234567890")) // the output is 1234567890
printAscii(L = 2, H = 1, T = "AACDE", rows = listOf("1234567890")) // the output is 1212567890
printAscii(L = 2, H = 1, T = "ABCBA", rows = listOf("1234567890")) // the output is 1234563412
printAscii(L = 2, H = 1, T = "EDCBA", rows = listOf("1234567890")) // the output is 9078563412
printAscii(L = 2, H = 1, T = "AAAAA", rows = listOf("1234567890")) // the output is 1212121212
```

Now you can see that the character `A` in the string `T` is related to the substring `12` in the string in `rows`, the character `B` in `T` is related to the substring `34` in `rows` and so on. When we changed `L` to 2, each character in `T` is related to a substring of size 2 in `rows` (you can try with `L` equals to 3 if you want, but make sure to add 5 characters in the first element of `rows`, which is the size of the string `T`).

Generally speaking, when `H` is equal to `1`, each character in `T` is related to a subtring of size `L` of the first element of `rows` (remember this!). But how to calculate which substring belongs to some character?

Notice that,

- when `L == 1`, `A` is related to the substring starting at `0`, `B` is related to the substring starting at `1`, `C` is related to the substring starting at `2` and so on;
- when `L == 2`, `A` is related to the substring starting at `0`, `B` is related to the substring starting at `2`, `C` is related to the substring starting at `4` and so on.

Can you guess the pattern for `L == 3`? The pattern is simple: calculate the distance between some letter to `A` (for example, the distance between `A` and `B` is 1, the distance between `A` and `E` is 4). Multiply this distance by `L` and get the start position of the substring.

So, for example, when `L == 2`, `C` is related to the substring starting at **4**. Applying our method, the distance between `C` and `A` is 2. Multiplying by `L`, which is 2, we have 2 * 2 = **4**, which is the start position of the substring.

Since the substring has a size of `L`, as we discovered above, to get the final position of the substring, we can add `L` to the start position.

Based on the information above, we can write the Kotlin code.

- how to calculate the distance between some character `c` and `'A'`? Answer: `c - 'A'`
- how to get the start position of the substring? Answer: `(c - 'A') * L`
- how to get the end position of the substring? Answer: `(c - 'A') * L + L`
- how to get a substring from the first element of `rows`? Answer: `rows[0].substring((c - 'A') * L, (c - 'A') * L + L)`

This is for `H == 1`, but you can increase its value and lead to the same conclusion.

For your second question, you can take a look at [this site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), specially at the section **Negated Character Classes**. Regex has nothing to do with Kotlin, but you can use Regex in Kotlin code.

Simply speaking, `[^A-Z]` in Regex means "match a single character that is not between A and Z", as well `[^0-9]` means "match a single character that is not between 0 and 9". If you want to match a single character that is between A and Z, just remove the caret, i.e. `[A-Z]`.

That being said, `.replace("[^A-Z]".toRegex(), "[")` means "match a single character that is not between A and Z and replace this character with `[`". Why `[`? Remember that `'B' - 'A' == 1` and `'E' - 'A' == 4`? If you follow the train, you'll see that `'Z' - 'A' == 25`. The character right next `'Z'` in the ASCII table is `[`, so `'[' - 'A' == 26`. Because of that, any character `c` that is not between A and Z will evaluate the expression `c - 'A'` to 26.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a very long and detailed answer, and it helps a lot. 
I understood most of it, and some parts I had to re-read 10 times to get it.

I will try it printing step by step to have a better idea.

The only part that I still don't get is the (c - 'A') * L  and (c - 'A') * L + L part. why does it multiply it by the length?

Comment: Oh and also, I don't undesrtand the regex part, what does that [^A-Z] mean? sorry if it's a basic question but I searched a little but got more confused. Does the " ^ " try to exclude the letters from A to Z? is it the only way to exclude something?

Comment: I've edited my answer, please let me know if you understand now. Happy coding!